Adding characters to a string of specific rows in R
I've seen many reproducible examples of both aspects of this, but can't quite get my head to work out how to apply concepts to real data!
I have a dataframe of 2 multiple columns, but the 2 of Interest are NGR and Buffer so here is an example of that data
df <- data.frame(
NGR = c("SD93950023","SD9501","SD954012"),
name = c("jk", "rho", "hb"),
Buffer = c(0,500,0))

df

I'd like to add characters within the string for NGR, BUT only for specific row. So, i'd like SD9501 to be changed to SD955015. Now, by data frame has 1300 rows, so i'd like that to be replicated across all rows which have Buffer value of 500 as they all have the same format of NGR (ABXXXX)
I can see that suggestions such as this can be applied to a single string
old <- "SD5464"

add into 5th character
n <- 5

add into 8th character
n2 <- 8

tell it what number to add into the 2 characters
regmatches(old, `attr<-`(n, "match.length", 0)) <- "5"
regmatches(old, `attr<-`(n2, "match.length", 0)) <- "5"

old

but to apply it to every row in my dataframe which has Buffer = 500 i've struggled to work out. I assume a function would work? but how to write that function I cannot seem to get to work correctly!
I have a preference for working in Tidyverse if possible.
Help appreciated.

With tidyverse use mutate() along with if_else() to conditionally edit the NGR column for rows where Buffer == 500: in this case we use a custom function pasteString to place in our fives.
Here is a quick and very professional drawing of what paste0(substr(oldString, 1, 4), "5", substr(oldString, 5, nchar(oldString))) does.

substr(oldString, 1, 4) extracts the characters within positions 1 and 4 from oldString = "SD54"
nchar(oldString) retrieves the number characters in oldString = 6
paste0() is a function that concatenates elements together without something in between -> that's why there is a 0
The function pasteString pastes a "5" into the oldString two times in succession, first in between 4 and 5, and then in between 7 and 8


# Function to insert "5" at the 5th position and then a "5" at the 8th position
pasteString <- function(oldString) {
  # Insert "5" at the 5th position
  oldString <- paste0(substr(oldString, 1, 4), "5", substr(oldString, 5, nchar(oldString)))
  # Insert "5" at the 8th position
  oldString <- paste0(substr(oldString, 1, 7), "5", substr(oldString, 8, nchar(oldString)))
  return(oldString)
}

# Modify the NGR column conditionally
df <- df %>%
  mutate(NGR = if_else(
    Buffer == 500,   # Only apply where Buffer == 500
    pasteString(NGR), # Replace NGR using the pasteString function
    NGR              # Else leave the old value
  ))

Result:
          NGR name Buffer
1 SD93950023   jk      0
2   SD955015  rho    500
3   SD954012   hb      0


Thanks G-Man - however I notice that it changes SD9501 to SD95051, rather than SD9501 to SD955015?

Apologies, yes you were right, we can use a custom function to paste in the 5 two times!

In base R, you can use regex in gsub here with conditional indexing and it should be pretty fast.
df$NGR[df$Buffer == 500] <- gsub("(^.{4})(.{0,3})(.*$)",
                                 "\\15\\25\\3",
                                 df$NGR[df$Buffer == 500])

#          NGR name Buffer
# 1 SD93950023   jk      0
# 2   SD955015  rho    500
# 3   SD954012   hb      0

A tidyverse approach would be:
df %>%
  mutate(NGR = if_else(Buffer == 500,
                       stringr::str_replace(NGR, "(^.{4})(.{0,3})(.*$)", "\\15\\25\\3"),
                       NGR))

But base seems to be faster:
bigdf <- df[rep(1:3, 1e4),]

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  base = bigdf$NGR[bigdf$Buffer == 500] <- gsub("(^.{4})(.{0,3})(.*$)",
                                 "\\15\\25\\3",
                                 bigdf$NGR[bigdf$Buffer == 500]),
  tidyverse = bigdf %>%
    mutate(NGR = if_else(Buffer == 500,
                       stringr::str_replace(NGR, "(^.{4})(.{0,3})(.*$)", "\\15\\25\\3"),
                       NGR))
)

Unit: milliseconds
      expr       min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
      base  6.156887 14.92186 23.73802 24.10711 31.93427 45.58362   100  a 
 tidyverse 19.187976 29.83164 32.41717 31.57325 35.14590 55.64708   100   b

